# Error in redirect URL for POST in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am getting this error when I run my Jmeter script through Maven:

> Error in redirect URL for POST http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signin HTTP/1.1
>   Could not sanitize URL: /private/index.html

I tried setting HTTP Request Implementation to `Java` and also provided http:// in front of the URL, but it still didn't work. Any suggestions for this?

Below is the complete Jmeter log.

```
    2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
    2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: E:\Maven Workspace\jmeterdemo\target\jmeter\bin\user.properties 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from:        E:\Maven Workspace\jmeterdemo\target\jmeter\bin\system.properties 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2013 The Apache Software Foundation 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.10 r1533061 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_45 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Windows 7 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=6.1 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=Cp1252 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=E:\Maven Workspace\jmeterdemo\target\jmeter 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =E:\Maven Workspace\jmeterdemo\target\jmeter\bin 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =E:\Maven Workspace\jmeterdemo\target\jmeter\bin 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 192.168.182.1 Name: RLE0228 FullName: RLE0228.RLINDIA.COM 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='E:\Maven Workspace\jmeterdemo\target\jmeter\bin' 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='E:\Maven Workspace\jmeterdemo\src\test\jmeter' 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading file: E:\Maven Workspace\jmeterdemo\src\test\jmeter\dashboard.jmx 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.5 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1519088 
2015/08/27 12:05:34 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_ 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is  
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is  
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is  
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Listeners will be started after enabling running version 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Running test (1440657335435) 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 5 threads for group Thread Group. 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 5 ramp-up 5 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: jmeterthread.startearlier=true (see jmeter.properties) 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Running PostProcessors in forward order 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: Maximum connection retries = 10 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = RLE0228 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Setting up HTTPS TrustAll scheme 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: Using default SSL protocol: TLS 
2015/08/27 12:05:35 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: SSL session context: per-thread 
2015/08/27 12:05:36 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 
2015/08/27 12:05:37 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3 
2015/08/27 12:05:38 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-4 
2015/08/27 12:05:39 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-5 
2015/08/27 12:05:44 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for POST http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signin HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /private/index.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /private/index.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:05:44 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:05:44 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for POST http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signin HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /private/index.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /private/index.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:05:44 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:05:45 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for POST http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signin HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /private/index.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /private/index.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:05:45 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:05:45 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for POST http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signin HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /private/index.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /private/index.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:05:45 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:05:46 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for POST http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signin HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /private/index.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /private/index.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:05:46 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:08 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for GET http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signout HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /public/login.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /public/login.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:08 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at 

    org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:09 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for GET http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signout HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /public/login.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /public/login.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:10 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:10 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for GET http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signout HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /public/login.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /public/login.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:10 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:10 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for GET http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signout HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /public/login.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /public/login.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:10 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:11 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: Error in redirect URL for GET http://xx.153.xx.33:3001/auth/signout HTTP/1.1
    Could not sanitize URL: /public/login.html
     java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /public/login.html
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:337)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:11 ERROR - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleEnd called twice java.lang.Throwable: Invalid call sequence
    at org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.sampleEnd(SampleResult.java:1033)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:390)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2015/08/27 12:06:15 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2 
2015/08/27 12:06:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-5 
2015/08/27 12:06:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2015/08/27 12:06:17 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3 
2015/08/27 12:06:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-4 
2015/08/27 12:06:18 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
```

Comment: You said you tried, but this error specifically mentions that the leading `http://` is missing

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted to be useful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed in recent versions of JMeter, try using JMeter 2.13 instead of 2.10, see:

2.12:

- http://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56231
- http://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56207

2.11:

- http://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55717

You should usually ensure you upgrade to later versions as soon as possible.

Comment: It worked after updating to latest version of Jmeter 2.13